# How can I retry a failed test?

Tags: continuous-integration, cypress

I'll sometimes have 1 or 2 tests that fail in CI, and rerunning the build causes them to pass.

How can I automatically re-run these flaky tests so my build will pass the first time? Is there something similar to `mocha`'s `this.retries`?

For example, I have a test that fails with "The element has an effective height of 0x0" about 10% of the time:

```
cy.visit('/')
cy.get('.my-element').click() // sometimes fails with not visible error
```

Comment: Good point, this one is quite useful

Comment: @bkucera it might be useful to show concrete scenarios in the question. Do you have unit tests around the plugin? Otherwise this is more like an advert than the a SO question

Comment: @eric99 it&#39;s a question we get in gitter frequently, and there&#39;s a GitHub issue asking for the feature. I cross post Q&amp;A here when a question comes in frequently from cypress users, but I agree an example would be helpful

Comment: So how did you test this plugin?

Comment: @eric99 There are tests in the repo, please direct any further questions in the issues there, as this is no longer relevant to this question.

Comment: I was just hoping you would produce a more substantive question for future reference.

Comment: Not true, if you had some tests they might serve to illustrate the problem you are solving. Unfortunately the code you added to the question does not really illustrate anything, so perhaps your tests could be shown to fill the gap.

Comment: You will be aware that in SO, questions should show minimal, reproducible code for the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188479/discussion-between-bkucera-and-eric99).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Update (v5.0.0)

Cypress now has built-in retry support.

You can set test retries in Cypress 5.0 via configuration in `cypress.json`

```json
{
  "retries": 1
}
```

or specify different options for runMode and openMode:

```json
{
  "retries": {
    "runMode": 1,
    "openMode": 3
  }
}
```

`runMode` allows you to define the number of test retries when running cypress run

`openMode` allows you to define the number of test retries when running cypress open

You can turn on test retries for just a single test or suite via test options:

```js
it('my test', {
  retries: 2
}, () => {
  // ...
})

// or

describe('my suite', {
  retries: 2
}, () => {
  // ...
})
```

If a test fails in a `beforeEach`, `afterEach`, or in the test body, it will be retried. Failures in beforeAll and afterAll hooks will not retry.

---

#### Old answer:

Official Support for test retries is on the way, but there's a plugin for that. [`cypress-plugin-retries`](https://github.com/Bkucera/cypress-plugin-retries)

**Disclosure: I'm the creator of the plugin.**

#### **Installation**

Add the plugin to devDependencies

```
npm install -D cypress-plugin-retries
```

At the top of `cypress/support/index.js`:

```
require('cypress-plugin-retries')
```

#### **Usage**

Use the environment variable `CYPRESS_RETRIES` to set the retry number:

```
CYPRESS_RETRIES=2 npm run cypress
```

**or** use `Cypress.env('RETRIES')` in your spec file:

```
Cypress.env('RETRIES', 2)
```

**or** on a per-test or per-hook basis, set the retry number:

> Note: this plugin **adds Cypress.currentTest** and you should only access it in the context of this plugin.

```js
it('test', () => {
    Cypress.currentTest.retries(2)
})
```

Note: [Please refer to this issue for updates about official cypress retry support](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1313)

Comment: does it work with cypress cucumber as well? I added `env: { "retries": 2}` in `cypress.json` and import `'cypress-plugin-retries';` in `/support/index.js`, but I don't see any retries happening. Any thoughts please?

Comment: You need uppercase 'RETRIES'

Comment: Yeah, that solved it. I also had to add the `cypress-plugin-retries` to types as I am using typescript.

Comment: @bkucera can we perform retry for only desired failed test cases?

Comment: Cypress.currentTest.retries(3)

Comment: @bkucera I am using cypress cucumber and typescript.I am not able to do that in that setup. Is there any option in that also? I

Comment: seems like the `before` hook is not retried, so if the failure is in your test setup it wont retry it

Answer (score 4):

For retry, you can add it in your config as below

```
{
  "retries": {
    // Configure retry attempts for `cypress run`
    // Default is 0
    "runMode": 2,
    // Configure retry attempts for `cypress open`
    // Default is 0
    "openMode": 0
  }
}
```

but instead of adding above I prefer to add (Which works for both run and open mode)

**"retries": 1**

[image]

Points to consider

1. You need cypress version > 5
2. As of now in cypress, you can retry test, not entire spec which will be a great ability to make tests more robust. I have already voted this as a critical feature (Also this one of the most voted for now)
   Ref:
   https://portal.productboard.com/cypress-io/1-cypress-dashboard/tabs/1-under-consideration

Answer (score 3):

Cypress 5 now has a native support for retries. Check: https://cypress.io/blog/2020/08/19/introducing-test-retries-in-cypress-5-0

Answer (score 0):

Cypress supports test retries as of version [5.0.0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#5-0-0), released on 8/19/2020.  These are present to reduce test flakiness and continuous integration build failures.  This feature is documented in the online Cypress documentation under the [Test Retries](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries#Introduction) guide.

By default, tests will not retry when they fail.  To retry failing tests, test retries need to be [enabled in the configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries#Configure-Test-Retries).

Retries can be configured separately for run mode (`cypress run`) vs. open mode (`cypress open`), as these will typically be different.

There are two ways to configure retries: globally, and per test or test suite.

### [Global Configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries#Global-Configuration)

The Cypress [configuration file](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-open) (`cypress.json` by default) allows configuring the retry attempt either per mode or for all modes.

To use a different value per mode:

```json
{
  "retries": {
    "runMode": 2,
    "openMode": 0
  }
}
```

To use the same value for both modes:

```json
{
  "retries": 1
}
```

### [Single test configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries#Individual-Test-s)

A [test's configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Test-Configuration) can specify the number of retry attempts specific to that test:

> ```javascript
> // Customize retry attempts for an individual test
> describe('User sign-up and login', () => {
>   // `it` test block with no custom configuration
>   it('should redirect unauthenticated user to sign-in page', () => {
>     // ...
>   })
>
>   // `it` test block with custom configuration
>   it(
>     'allows user to login',
>     {
>       retries: {
>         runMode: 2,
>         openMode: 1,
>       },
>     },
>     () => {
>       // ...
>     }
>   )
> })
> ```

### [Single test suite configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries#Test-Suite-s)

A test suite's configuration can specify the number of retry attempts for each test within that suite:

> ```javascript
> // Customizing retry attempts for a suite of tests
> describe('User bank accounts', {
>   retries: {
>     runMode: 2,
>     openMode: 1,
>   }
> }, () => {
>   // The per-suite configuration is applied to each test
>   // If a test fails, it will be retried
>   it('allows a user to view their transactions', () => {
>     // ...
>   }
>
>   it('allows a user to edit their transactions', () => {
>     // ...
>   }
> })
> ```